# How to select multiple answers in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm in a dilemma where I could initially choose only one answer. But now there is a case if isMultiChoice is true then it will select multiple answers in that question.

```
  String _selection = '';
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  List<Answers?> _answers = [];

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _answers = List<Answers?>.filled(widget.questions.length, null);
}

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    Question question = widget.questions[_currentIndex];
    final List<Answers>? options = question.answers;
    if (options != null && options.contains(question.answers)) {
      options.addAll(question.answers!);
    }

    return Card(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        ...options!.map((answer) => widget
                    .questions[_currentIndex]
                    .isMultiChoice ==
                true
            ? RadioListTile(    // Choose multiple answers
                groupValue: _selection,
                title: Text(
                  HtmlUnescape()
                      .convert("${answer.content}"),
                  style: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >
                          800
                      ? TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0)
                      : null,
                ),
                value: answer,
                activeColor: Colors.blue,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  print(val);
                  setState(() {
                    _selection = val;
                  });
                },
              ).toList()
            : RadioListTile<Answers>(   // Choose one answer
                title: Text(
                  HtmlUnescape()
                      .convert("${answer.content}"),
                  style: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >
                          800
                      ? TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0)
                      : null,
                ),
                groupValue: _answers[_currentIndex],
                value: answer,
                onChanged: (Answers? value) {
                  print(value);
                  setState(() {
                    _answers[_currentIndex] = value!;
                    print(_answers[_currentIndex]);
                  });
                },
              )),
      ],
    ),);
}
```

And here is the question model class:

```
class Question {
  final int? id;
  final bool? isMultiChoice;
  final String? content;
  final String? correctAnswer;
  final List<Answers>?
      answers; // Change the data type of answers to List<Answers>?

  Question(
      {this.id,
      this.isMultiChoice,
      this.content,
      this.correctAnswer,
      this.answers});

  Question.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data)
      : id = data["id"],
        isMultiChoice = data["isMultiChoice"],
        content = data["content"],
        correctAnswer = data["correct_answer"],
        answers = data["answers"] != null
            ? (data["answers"] as List<dynamic>)
                .map((e) => Answers.fromJson(e))
                .toList()
            : null;

  static List<Question> fromData(List<Map<String, dynamic>> data) {
    return data.map((question) => Question.fromMap(question)).toList();
  }
}

class Answers {
  int? id;
  String? content;
  bool? isCorrect;

  Answers({this.id, this.content, this.isCorrect});

  Answers.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    content = json['content'];
    isCorrect = json['isCorrect'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['content'] = this.content;
    data['isCorrect'] = this.isCorrect;
    return data;
  }

  contains(Answers answer) {
    return this.id == answer.id;
  }

  void add(Answers answer) {
    if (!this.contains(answer)) {
      throw Exception('Answer not found');
    }
    this.id = answer.id;
  }

  void remove(Answers answer) {
    if (this.contains(answer)) {
      this.id = null;
    }
  }

  map(Function(dynamic a) f) {
    if (id != null) {
      f(this);
    }
  }
}
```

My Api Get:

```
"listQuestion": [
        {
            "id": 2126,
            "content": "For shorter Sprints, Sprint Retrospective Is usually shorter.",
            "isMultiChoice": false,
            "totalAnswer": 2,
            "answers": [
                {
                    "id": 7335,
                    "content": "FALSE",
                    "isCorrect": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 7334,
                    "content": "TRUE",
                    "isCorrect": true
                }
            ]
        },
{
            "id": 2235,
            "content": "The Scrum Pillars are:",
            "isMultiChoice": true,
            "totalAnswer": 4,
            "answers": [
                {
                    "id": 7684,
                    "content": "Transparency, Adaptation ",
                    "isCorrect": true
                },
                {
                    "id": 7682,
                    "content": "Inspection",
                    "isCorrect": true
                },
                {
                    "id": 7681,
                    "content": "Agility, Focus",
                    "isCorrect": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 7683,
                    "content": "Respect",
                    "isCorrect": false
                }
            ]
        },
]
```

And Api Post Result:

```
[
    {
        "questionId":276,
        "answerId":[1018, 1019]
    },
    {
        "questionId":274,
        "answerId":[1009]
    }
]
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong, like when selecting multiple answers, and all are returned as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same question as you.

```
final questionId = widget.questions[_currentIndex].id;
final answerId = _answers[_currentIndex];
final questionResult =
    QuestionResult(questionId: questionId, answerId: answerId);
_questionResults?.add(questionResult);
```